# How to retrieve multiple values from the database using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="APIToDatabase.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function connectDb()
  {
  var ConnDB = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
  ConnDB.ConnectionString="Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:yueloongserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=LocationDatabase;Uid=;Pwd=;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;";
 ConnDB.Open();
 var Rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
  var tempstr = "";
 Rs.Open("select Latitude,Longitude from dbo.GPS",ConnDB);
 while(!Rs.EOF === true)
 {
  tempstr = tempstr + Rs("Latitude")  + "" + Rs("Longitude");


 Rs.MoveNext;
}
  test.innerHTML = tempstr;
}
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>


  <p><div id=test> </div>
  <p><input id="button1" type="button"   value="Run"   name="button1" onclick="connectDb();"></p>


  </body>
     </script>
```

Hi, i am having the problem where i am able to only retrieve one column from the database. However, i would like to retrieve all the columns from the database table.

Comment: "all the data from the database." or "all the columns for each row from the database?"

Comment: all the columns from a specific table. Sorry my bad i make a mistake

Comment: select * from dbo.GPS

Comment: Tried still not working only if i put the column deviceimei, it will show the rest it will not show

Comment: You have to update your tempstr to include the other columns

Comment: so i have to create another variable to store the data from other columns ?

Comment: You're just placing them in the innerHtml so you can place them all in there as one long string

Comment: I noticed that even if i tried to get the other column from the table, it still return the same column values as the previous

Comment: so i put var largeString = '"Hello\n\
This is long!"'; then     largeString = tempstr; or ?